# Turning on the locked screen Ionic 4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, alarm, mobile-application, off-screen

I want to turn the mobile screen on when the screen is locked in order to develope a reminder mobile app.
Can anyone help me with any cordova plugin or third party library ?

Comment: did you want to schedule notification?

Comment: No. You know alarms work even when the screen is turned off. I just want to do like that.

Comment: I'm struggeling with the same issue. Would be great if someone could share his solution here. :-)